# How declare for in function with parameter

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I new in Python. I don't know how work this.

I have this code:

```
def main():
 a=input("Type number")
 e=int(a)
 function2(e);
def function2(e):
 for h in range(e):
  print("X")
main();
```

write me this error:
Traceback (most recent call last)
for h in range(e):
NameError: name 'e' is not defined

Comment: Necj, I'm writing out an answer for you but they are usually descriptive and rather take awhile to create. Hold tight and I'll take care of this.

Comment: Your program, precisely as it appears in the question, [runs perfectly](http://ideone.com/534qsT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because of an indentation error, and you forgot to put a `:` after your for loop:

```
def main():
    a = input("Type number")
    e = int(a)
    function2(e)


def function2(e):
    for h in range(e):
        print("X")


main()
```

Also, no semicolons are required in python.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be a series of misunderstandings in general. Your errors in your code are simple, but let's see if I can't walk you through some concepts so that when I show you the fixed code, you understand it completely. Keep in mind that I expect you already know a lot of it, but I'm writing this answer not just for you, but for any other beginners who stumble upon this page. :)

It seems we can cover the following topics (each concept is simple in itself, but you need to get them completely in order to get the next one):

- Variables in programming
- Variables in python
- Whitespace in python
- Functions: Parameters vs Arguments
- Solution: fixing your code

### Variables in programming

Variables, as you probably know, are simply the labels we give to data. In most languages, you have to declare the variable first so that you can have the appropriate *type* assigned to it (that is, so the computer knows whether it's an *integer*, a *string*, a *boolean*, etc). Thus, you need the following code:

```
int myVariable1 = 3;
string myVariable2 = "hello";
bool myVariable3 = true;
```

(In some languages, you need to declare variables and *then* assign a value to them.)

### Variables in python

Python, apart from many starter languages, is dynamically typed. This means that the *variables* (the labels on the data) have no type, but the *values* do.

That means that your code can look like this

```
 myVariable1 = 3
 myVariable2 = "hello"
 myVariable3 = True
```

And python can figure out what types to use, based on the data assigned to the variables.

(Note: in python, you don't need `;` to end a line, and `boolean` values are capitalized (`True`, `False))

### Whitespace in python

Python was designed to be easy to read. Computers use hints inside the language (`(), [], {}, :, ;, etc`) to know what's going on. In Python, `whitespace` (      ) is part of the hinting, or `syntax`. In most languages, `whitespace` is ignored but because Python does not ignore it, it can be used to format your languages in a visually pleasing way. In C++,

```
function myFunction() {string myString = "wow such learn good job, many doge wow";}
```

and

```
function myFunction() {
string myString = "wow such learn good job, many doge wow";
}
```

are the same. You can see how this could confuse a new programmer, as it doesn't even *look* the same. But in Python, the code *has to look like*:

```
def myFunction():
    myString = "wow such learn good job, many doge wow"
```

And it is this uniformity that makes Python so much easier to work with, for a lot of people.

### Functions: Parameters vs Arguments

In every decent language, the use of functions is vital, and understanding them completely is even more vital.

Functions can easily be related to basic concepts of Algebra. Functions already exist in Algebra, this being why the comparison is so easiy.

In Algebra, a function is an equation with variables in it. Inside the function, work is ready to be done with the equation that is set up, and it's just waiting for you to fill in the missing pieces. That is to say,

```
f(x) = 3 + 2x + x^2
```

is a function that is ready to go, but it needs to you put in `x`.

This is the same thing in programming. When I write

```
def myFunction(x):
    3+2x+x**2
```

I am writing the exact same thing as f(x); A working equation that depends on the information it is given.

A note: Not all programming functions do *math* exactly, some operate on strings, but they all alter data and that is my point. Some functions don't even *need* input, because they operate on data independent of what you're doing. Here, the comparison falls apart somewhat, but I hope you're still onboard.

So, what are **arguments** and what are **parameters**?

When defining the function and then calling the function:

```
def myFunction(x): #defining the function f(x)
    3+2x+x**2


print myFunction(3) #calling the function f(x) where x=3
```

The **parameter** is `x` in the first line. **Parameters** are the variables that you put into the *definition* of a function.

The **argument** is the `3` that you put in *place* of the `x` when you *called* the function. **Arguments** are the values you use to fill in the variables in a function.

As such, you are now giving the function the value `3` and it solves the following:

```
3+2*(3)+(3)^2
3+6+9
9+9
18
```

The resulting output will of course `print`:

```
18.
```

### Solution: fixing your code

Now that we've gone over all of the base concepts that lead to your code getting errors. Here is your original code:

```
 def main():
  a=input("Type number")
  e=int(a)
  function2(e);
def function2(e):
 for h in range(e):
  print("X")
main();
```

There are a multitude of errors here:

- Your `def main():` is written mostly correct, but the indentation may not be sufficient. Python standard, the one that may confuse less sophisticated interpreters for it, requires about **4 spaces** as its `whitespace` and indentation.
- Your `def main():` also uses a `;` at the end, which, as a difference between Python and lots of other languages, is a syntax problem. Python doesn't need `;`, and just removing it fixes that error.
- Your `def function2(e):` appears to have no errors aside from the `whitespace` problem that we saw in `def main():`
- Your `def function2(e):` makes use of `print()`, which, while this is no error, is a syntax difference that is significant between Python 2.7 and Python 3.3; For this reason, I'll be adding the tag `Python 3.3` for future-proofing reasons.
- When you call `main();`, the ending `;` is unneccessary, and can be removed.

Here is a revised version of your code that works.

```
def main():
    a = input("Type number")
    e = int(a)
    function2(e)

def function2(e):
    for h in range(e):
        print("X")

main()
```

Do you understand how it works completely now? Sorry for all the reading, hopefully you are much more comfortable now, having gone through the entire thing!

For any questions, don't hesitate to ask in a comment below.

Happy Coding!

PS - I see that you already picked the best answer. But maybe after reading this one, you'll change your mind ;)

Comment: If this helps you, consider picking best answer-- if you like the others better though, no worries! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a colon `:` inside of your `function2`, so if you change that bit to:

```
def function2(e):
 for h in range(e):
  print("X")
```

You should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

None Any mistake or synatx erorr in Your Code It is Working Fine .
And You can indent the code by (tab) or by one space or any thing else .as long as you are saved the Blocks